# Laravel linking using controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

see this apple icons, these are rendering from foreach loop in view, defined variable in controller . i can change each icons but not able to assign link to each icon.

[image: see this apple icons, these are rendering from foreach loop using controller variable. i can change each icons but not able to assign link to each icon.]Hello guys i am stuck in linking  using laravel controller.

my code is something like that: (i have a service page which has sub services page there is only one view which is using controller variable to showing data. i want each page button have different links. links can be static so i can putt it from controller. dont have any database attached to this solution. i want each href as a separate link)

This is view:

```
<?php $index=-1; ?>
@foreach ($third_fold_3_technologies_list as $item)
    <?php $index++; ?>
    <a href="#"><span class="{{ $item }}"></span></a>
@endforeach
```

This is controller:

```
$third_fold_3_technologies_list = [
    'icon-appleinc',
    'icon-appleinc',
    'icon-appleinc',
];
```

Comment: ***i want each href as a separate link*** show us example please

Comment: the example code is above. what you mean by example browser screenshot?

Comment: meant what you expecting as  output

Comment: oh ok i want to redirect to another page. like i want to put custom link by my self using controller variable.

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem.

Comment: let me share you the screehot and some details

Comment: please see the image attached and desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use associative array.

```
$third_fold_3_technologies_list = [
     'http://<link1>' => 'icon-appleinc',
     '/<link2>'       => 'icon-appleinc',
     '<link3>'        => 'icon-appleinc',
];
```

Then in your view

```
@foreach ($third_fold_3_technologies_list as $link => $class)
    <a href="{{ $link }}"><span class="{{ $class }}"></span></a>
@endforeach
```